# Create dynamic resources using 'for_each' or 'for'

Tags: terraform

I want to create multiple resources using this:

```
resource "group" "list" {
 g_name      = group_name
 p_name      = project_name
}
```

The input local variable is nested:

```
> local.input
{
  "group" = [
    {
      "name" = "group1"
      "projects" = [
        "project1",
        "project3",
      ]
    },
    {
      "name" = "group2"
      "projects" = [
        "project18",
        "project31",
      ]
    },
  ]
```

I am able to transform it into a better form:

```
> flatten([for grp_key, group in local.input.group: [for project in group.projects: { group_name=group.name, project_name=project} ]])
[
  {
    "group_name" = "group1"
    "project_name" = "project1"
  },
  {
    "group_name" = "group1"
    "project_name" = "project3"
  },
  {
    "group_name" = "group2"
    "project_name" = "project18"
  },
  {
    "group_name" = "group2"
    "project_name" = "project31"
  },
]
```

I can not use `for_each` because it is not `map` neither `set`.

How could I create multiple resources using the `for` like:

```
resource "group" "list" {
  for item in ... : 
    g_name=item.group_name
    p_name=item.project_name
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `count`, and with it you should be able to access item by index: https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#the-count-object